# How configure email the at/batch results is sent to?

Tags: linux, centos, at

From the man page for at/batch, it says

```
The user will be mailed standard error and standard output from his 
commands, if any. Mail will be sent using the command /usr/sbin/sendmail. 
If at is executed from a su(1) shell, the owner of the login shell will 
receive the mail.
```

But how do configure what email address its sent to?

In cron can use the MAILTO enviroment variable, but can't see that anywhere within `at` or `batch`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way of doing that in the at invocation, but you could probably do something like this with the command you're calling via at:

```
 $ at 16:00
 at> some-command [arguments, &c.] 2>&1 | sendmail [-f <from-address>] <recipient>
 at> ^D
```

When the command runs, it will hand off its output to sendmail for delivery to the specified recipient, and in the quick test I've just run, this does work.

Of course, if you're already redirecting the output from some-command to go somewhere else, you might be out of luck -- but, then, you could always tee(1) the output, or add a final line to the at job calling sendmail to push out the message.